# Remove EntityReference from CRM 2015 value

Tags: c#, crm, entityreference, dynamics-crm-2015

I am doing a tool to synchronize some to data between CRM and another application.
Now I have to remove the value from a EntityReference. I am trying in this way:

```
contact.ParentCustomerId = null;
```

But it does not work. That does not give me any error bur when I go to CRM via browser the field is till valorized.
I have also tried in this way:

```
contact.ParentCustomerId = new EntityReference(Crm.Context.Account.EntityLogicalName, Guid.Empty);
```

but this give me a runtime error.

How can I solve? Thank you

**UPDATE :**

```
 Crm.Context.Contact contatto = ContattiTOA.Transform(c, account); //Inside the transform you can see that line of code I posted before..

 var entityToUpdate = this._context
                                .ContactSet
                                .Where(cont => cont.new_SIP_id == contatto.new_SIP_id || cont.Id == contatto.Id)
                                .First();

        if (entityToUpdate.new_SynchronizewithSIP.HasValue && entityToUpdate.new_SynchronizewithSIP.Value == true)
        {
            contatto.Id = entityToUpdate.Id;
            contatto.OwnerId = entityToUpdate.OwnerId;
            contatto.EntityState = EntityState.Changed;

            request = new UpdateRequest { Target = contatto };
        }

        requests.Requests.Add(request);

        ExecuteMultipleResponse responses = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)this._context.Execute(requests);

        foreach (var responseItem in responses.Responses)
        {
            if (responseItem.Fault != null)
            {
                ... // I never fall in here
            }
        }
```

Comment: contact.ParentCustomerId = null; is correct, do you save the record after?

Comment: yes... All other fields are correctly changed... but not that one...

Comment: I concur that the line of code is correct, so the bug is likely somewhere else

Comment: I have done some update so you can see all the code... I did a debug everything seems correct...

Comment: In the code you posted I don't see the line `contact.ParentCustomerId`.

Comment: It is inside the first line of code... I wrote a comment as you can see.. The `Transform` method is a reallt stupid method... It is just a mapping from my domain object to the CRM object.. In this mapping there is that line of code

Comment: Have you tried isolating the code to just the contact.ParentCustomerId = null? You may want to try running just that to  see if that is for sure your your issue.

Comment: Yes, I have just tried... but no difference